# Can Wordpress be used like a CMS?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, perch

In my last project, I have used Perch CMS because it gave my huge flexibility and allowed me to edit many field in the same page. On the other hand Wordpress allow you to only change one or two field on a single page :(

So my question is, can Wordpress give the same flexibility Perch gave me (editing many fields on a single page)?

If not, is there a better CMS that you recommend?

Please note that I only plan to use Wordpress as a CMS and not as Blogging platform.

Here is video showing you what I meant by editing many fields on a single page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUsY4iZYc0I

FYI, the reason I'm looking for other option other than Perch is because 1) Perch isn't free 2) I think the security of Perch is not as strong as Wordpress.

Lastly, please excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add custom meta fields on your page or post what you want a best plugin for that is ACF(advanced custom fields)**